# Why cy.wait doesn't handle request, with cy.intercept property entered via variable?

Tags: cypress, cypress-intercept

In case, if 'Panasonic' is entered directly in cy.intercept property, it works ok

```js
cy.intercept('GET', '**/part-number/search?q=Panasonic**').as('getPNList')
```

but in case if this value added via variable into cy.intercept property, it doesn't work and cy.wait falls with timeout. What could be the reason?

```js
let pnName = 'Panasonic'
    cy.intercept('GET', '**/part-number/search?q={@pnName}**').as('getPNList')
    cy.get('.select2-search__field').click().type(pnName)
    cy.wait('@getPNList').then((interception) => {
        expect(interception.response.statusCode).eq(200)
    })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm fairly certain your string interpolation is incorrect, and as such, your intercept is just looking for `'**/part-number/search?q={@pnName}**'` instead of replacing `{@pnName}` with the variable.

Try this instead:

```js
cy.intercept('GET', `**/part-number/search?q=${pnName}**`).as('getPNList')
```

[Check out more about string templates/string interpolation at MDN.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Answer (score 2):

Consider using the alternate format for query parameters

Ref: [Matching with RouteMatcher](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/intercept#Matching-with-RouteMatcher)

```js
const pnName = 'Panasonic'

cy.intercept({
  pathname: '**/part-number/search',
  query: {
    q: pnName,
  },
}).as('getPNList')
```